# Would like to keep submit button disabled using angular js on form load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am having html form and I would like to keep submit button disable on startup of form as by default it is enabled and takes input even if controls are empty.
Here is my code.
It works fine once you enter data & then removes it from input control but by default it does not.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Forms</title>
      <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
      <div ng-app = "mainApp" ng-controller = "studentController">

         <form name = "studentForm" novalidate>
            <table border = "0">
               <tr>
                  <td>Enter first name:</td>
                  <td><input name = "firstname" placeholder="name"  type = "text" ng-model = "firstName" required>
                     <span style = "color:red" ng-show = "studentForm.firstname.$dirty && studentForm.firstname.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show = "studentForm.firstname.$error.required">First Name is required.</span>
                     </span>
                  </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td>Enter Domain name: </td>
                  <td><input name = "domain" type = "text" ng-model = "domain" placeholder="domain" required>
                     <span style = "color:red" ng-show = "studentForm.domain.$dirty && studentForm.domain.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show = "studentForm.domain.$error.required">Last Name is required.</span>
                     </span>
                  </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td>Email: </td><td><input name = "email" type = "email"  ng-model = "email" placeholder="Email" length = "100" required>
                     <span style = "color:red" ng-show = "studentForm.email.$dirty && studentForm.email.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show = "studentForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
                        <span ng-show = "studentForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
                     </span>
                  </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <button ng-click = "reset()">Reset</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <button ng-disabled = "studentForm.firstname.$dirty &&
                        studentForm.firstname.$invalid || studentForm.domain.$dirty &&
                        studentForm.domain.$invalid || studentForm.email.$dirty &&
                        studentForm.email.$invalid" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
                  </td>
               </tr>

            </table>
         </form>
      </div>

      <script>
         var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

         mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.reset = function(){
            }

            $scope.reset();
         });
      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The submit listener should be on the form, not the submit button as the form can be submitted without clicking the submit button.

Comment: @RobG, I thought so too, but apparently browsers (Chrome at least), doesn't let you submit a form using, say, enter, if the submit button is disabled. It does let you if the submit button is omitted, though. [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/mhymdknc/). First form won't submit, while the second one will.

Comment: @GolezTrol—Safari and Omniweb, at least, do. And the submit listener should be on the form regardless, since once the submit button is enabled, the form can be submitted without selecting the submit button in all browsers (except some very old versions of IE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give $pristine for all the input elements

```
<button ng-disabled = "studentForm.firstname.$pristine || studentForm.domain.$pristine || studentForm.email.$pristine ||  studentForm.firstname.$dirty && studentForm.firstname.$invalid || studentForm.domain.$dirty && studentForm.domain.$invalid || studentForm.email.$dirty && studentForm.email.$invalid" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help,

```
        <button ng-disabled = "studentForm.$invalid" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Just need to add `studentForm.firstname.$pristine ||` in starting of `ng-disabled`.

Comment: Using this also when you just type the name it enables the submit button and does not throws any error for empty email & domain.

Comment: No, the code works fine here, I think yo are missing something.
`<button ng-disabled = "studentForm.firstname.$pristine || studentForm.firstname.$dirty &&
                        studentForm.firstname.$invalid || studentForm.domain.$dirty &&
                        studentForm.domain.$invalid || studentForm.email.$dirty &&
                        studentForm.email.$invalid" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>`

Comment: The issue is when you just enter the first name and presses the tab the submit button becomes enable.You can check it in firefox.

Comment: Try `<button ng-disabled = "studentForm.$invalid" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>`

Comment: This will make your condition short and sensible

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me -

```
<button ng-disabled = "!studentForm.firstname || !studentForm.domain || !studentForm.email">Submit</button>
```